# How do I replace elements in an array with a specific number in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm currently working with a 2d array in Python with values either 0 or 255. I want to replace 0 with -1 and 255 with 1. I currently have the following:

```
x=list(range(0,len(a)))
for i in x:
    for j in x:
        if a[i,j] == 0:
           a[i,j] = -1
        else:
           a[i,j] = 1
```

Where a is the name of the numpy array. However this replaces 0 with 255, which I suppose is a[-1]? How can I simply replace the values without this happening?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is `a`? Please make your example self-contained.

Comment: What is ``a``? Is it a ``list``, an ``array.array``, a ``numpy.array`` or something else?

Comment: You're setting everything that isn't zero to one...

Comment: What data type are the elements in a? That's what really matters here.

Comment: @nicomp that'll be it, they're numpy unsigned integers

Comment: If your dtype is ``uint8``, you *cannot* have a -1 value just as you cannot have a 0.5 or "Hello World" value.

Comment: `a  = np.where(a==0, -1, 1)`. Note that it will change dtype to int64